# items.remove if fetch response is {artists: null}

Tags: javascript

i'm trying (with no success) to hide an items if the fetch response is null. Let me explain.

i have an app:

```
  const isLoggedIn = app.session.user;
    const artistTitle = this.attrs.discussion.title().split(/\s+/).join('%20');
    const languageCode = app.forum.attribute('justoverclock-theaudiodb-api.langCode') || 'EN';

    // gestiamo gli errori nella risposta
    function handleErrors(response) {
      if (!response.ok) {
        throw Error(response.statusText);
      }
      return response;
    }

    if (isLoggedIn) {
      const artistApi = fetch('https://theaudiodb.com/api/v1/json/1/search.php?s=' + artistTitle)
        .then(handleErrors)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
          console.log(data)
          m.redraw();
          const arrayElem = 'strBiography' + languageCode;
          if (data.artists[0][arrayElem] === null) {
            data.artists[0][arrayElem] =
              'Oops! Description is not available in your language unfortunately...You can contribute to TheAudioDB.com by adding information about this artists in your language.';
          }
          const descArt = (document.getElementById('descArtist').innerText = data.artists[0][arrayElem].substring(0, 400) + '...');
          const thumbArtists = (document.getElementById('imgArtists').src = data.artists[0].strArtistThumb);
          const genreArtist = (document.getElementById('genreArtist').innerText =
            app.translator.trans('justoverclock-theaudiodb-api.forum.genres') + ': ' + data.artists[0].strStyle);
          const yearBorn = (document.getElementById('yearBorn').innerText =
            app.translator.trans('justoverclock-theaudiodb-api.forum.intFormedYear') + ': ' + data.artists[0].intFormedYear);
          const countryArtist = (document.getElementById('strcountry').innerText =
            app.translator.trans('justoverclock-theaudiodb-api.forum.countryart') + ': ' + data.artists[0].strCountry);
        })
        .catch((error) => console.log('This Artist does not exist ;) =>', artistTitle));
    }

    extend(DiscussionHero.prototype, 'items', function (items) {
      const isLoggedIn = app.session.user;
      if (isLoggedIn) {
        items.add(
          'artistDetailMusic',
          <div class="artistWrapper">
            <div id="containerArtist">
              <div id="contentArtist">
                <p class="artistDesc" id="descArtist"/>
                <div class="itemdescrip">
                  <div class="genreArtist" id="genreArtist"/>
                  <div class="yearBorn" id="yearBorn"/>
                  <div class="strcountry" id="strcountry"/>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div id="sidebarImgArtist">
              <img className="imgArtist" id="imgArtists" src=""/>
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      }
    });
  });
});
```

and it works pretty well when data is not empty, but it display the items even with no data. how can i remove the items if there's no data?

if i console.log(data) when is empty it shows

```
{
    "artists": null
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

```
if(data.artists === null) {
  document.getElementById("artistWrapper").style.display = "none";
}
```

Comment: nothing changed unfortunately, i've tried